# Camera buttons Mavic 2 controller not working as expected in Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I am facing an issue with the app I am developing and the Mavic 2 Pro. The issue relates to the camera buttons (i.e. shutter and video buttons). Indeed these buttons work just fine whenever the drone is not connected to my app, but as soon as the drone is connected to the app they stop working. The only feature that still works is the auto-focus when soft-pushing the shutter button (which has two stops).

This only happens with the Mavic 2 Pro, which makes me think this is an issue related with the SDK or with the drone firmware and not with my app. Indeed I have tested connecting my app to a Matrice 210 RTK, a P4P and a Mavic Pro and the camera buttons work as expected even when these drones are connected to the app.

I could add a listener on the remote controller state and trigger the take picture/record video actions from my app, but I believe this is a hack as these remote controller buttons actions should not be overwritten by the SDK.

Is there any specific action to be done on the Mobile SDK for the Mavic 2 Pro remote controller to work as expected? Has somebody made this work?

Cheers,

Nacho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The implementation of shoot photo button and record video button in MSDK have been removed, developers need to implement their own function by listening to the press events of Remote Controller for Mavic Pro and Mavic 2 platforms."

Was at in the 4.8 Android release notes, seems to be missing from the iOS release notes.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that since I'm developing for iOS. Although I do not get why they have done this only for two buttons and only for one kind of drone...